# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, ajax

Cuando se ejecuta mi código en ajax da este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange (http://localhost/LF/html/inicio.php:57:60)req.onreadystatechange @ inicio.php:57
>      inicio.php:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(…)req.onreadystatechange @ inicio.php:57

Éste es mi código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax(){
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
          document.getElementById('complemento').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
      }
      req.open('GET','header.php',true);
      req.send();
    }

    //linea que hace que se refresque la página cada segundo.
    setInterval(function(){ajax();}, 60000);
  </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax2(){
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
          document.getElementById('Amigos').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
      }
      req.open('GET','Amistades.php',true);
      req.send();
    }

    //linea que hace que se refresque la página cada segundo.
    setInterval(function(){ajax3();}, 1000);
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   ` function ajax3(){
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();`

      req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
          document.getElementById('publicacion').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
      }
      req.open('GET','publicacion.php',true);
      req.send();
    }

    //linea que hace que se refresque la página cada segundo.
    setInterval(function(){ajax2();}, 1000);
  </script>
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Hace falta que añadas el HTML de la página, ¿dónde están los elementos con ID "complemento", "Amigos" y "publicacion"? ¿en cuál de ellos recibes el error?

Comment: A parte de lo que te ha dicho Álvaro el primer **setInterval** se ejecuta cada 60 segundos y no cada segundo como indicas.